# What does mean by "start his pitch" means ?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0993846/synopsis)

> The man awkwardly **starts his pitch** before Jordan takes the pen away.

What does mean by "start his pitch" means ?

Answer (score 2):

This time, it's not an idiom. *Start* has the usual meaning of "begin". Let us examine some definitions of *pitch*.

> [pitch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch)
>
> 8. **a** :  an often high-pressure sales presentation
>
> [pitch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch)
>
> 35. (Marketing) slang a persuasive sales talk, esp one routinely repeated

So, the man awkwardly begins his presentation to make a sale to the audience.

I found a clip of the scene [here](https://youtu.be/Hh3bSzDQ1Po?t=302). Jordan (Leonardo DiCaprio's character) is there to train the audience to become good salespeople. He tells the man, "Sell me this pen", and the man begins to try to persuade Jordan to buy the pen. This is the man's awkward sales pitch.